# De onde surgiram os termos “fulano”, “beltrano” e “sicrano”?

Tags: etimologia, origem-histórica

Muitas vezes quando queremos mencionar pessoas indeterminada, ou “sem importância”, apenas para simbolizar existência de outros indivíduos, geralmente falamos: “fulano”, “beltrano” e “sicrano”.

De onde surgiram os termos “fulano”, “beltrano” e “sicrano”?

Comment: Viana, incluí os exemplos conhecidos mais antigos de cada uma das palavras, caso estejas interessado.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***Fulano***, de acordo com o dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003), vem do árabe *fulān*, que significa ‘alguém, um certo, determinado (indivíduo)’; também se encontra no português antigo *fuão* e *fulan*.

A origem das outras duas palavras é mais incerta, mas uma opinião comum entre os filólogos citados no Houaiss é que ambas foram adotadas ou alteradas para rimarem com *fulano*, o que faz sentido já que *beltrano* e *sicrano* são quase sempre usadas com *fulano*, e *fulano* parece ser a mais antiga das três palavras.

***Beltrano*** é segundo Antônio Geraldo da Cunha (*Dicionário Etimológico Nova Fronteira da Língua Portuguesa*) o nome próprio castelhano; segundo Antenor Nascentes vem do nome português equivalente, *Beltrão*, com a terminação alterada para *-ano* para rimar com *fulano* (Houaiss).

***Sicrano*** tem a origem mais problemática. Cito o Houaiss, desabreviando as abreviaturas:

> **sicrano** […] ETIM origem controversa, José Pedro Machado (*Dicionário Etimológico da Língua Portuguesa*) considera vocábulo de origem obscura, levantando a hipótese de ser talvez uma formação expressiva para rimar com *fulano*; compare com o espanhol *zutano* (1438 sob a forma *çutana*), vocábulo de origem incerta, segundo Corominas, que, no entanto, sugere tratar-se de uma interjeição *cit!* ou *çut!*, empregada como forma de chamamento e, logo, para nomear um desconhecido qualquer, cujo nome se ignora e, finalmente, adaptada à terminação de *fulano*; o espanhol apresenta diversas variantes, entre as quais *cicrano, citrano, cistrano*, formas que, segundo o autor, asseguram a indissociabilidade entre o espanhol *zutano* e o português *cicrano*;

***Ciclano*** ou ***siclano***, forma que o Bruno Lopes me trouxe à atenção, é uma variante de *sicrano* comum no Brasil e que também já se usou em Portugal, mas que eu desconhecia. Não vem nos dicionários, e não falta gente a dizer que “é termo inexistente” [(aqui)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=hfKRDgAAQBAJ&pg=PT118&dq=siclano&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig8bSOk-nVAhUESRoKHaskCa8Q6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=siclano&f=false) ou que é “errado” [(aqui)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=kJL0BgAAQBAJ&pg=PT69&dq=siclano&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig8bSOk-nVAhUESRoKHaskCa8Q6AEIOzAD#v=onepage&q=siclano&f=false). Mas a palavra aparece já em [1720 no *Vocabulario Portuguez e Latino* de Raphael Bluteau](https://books.google.pt/books?id=tMESsATvdyEC&pg=PA640&dq=siclano&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKucKZiOnVAhVD2xoKHa_0D3oQ6AEI2gIwMA#v=onepage&q=siclano&f=false), ainda que no verbete *sicrano*, portanto sem direito a verbete próprio. Depois parece desaparecer dos dicionários, mas encontra-se em várias publicações em Portugal no século XIX, e até ao presente no Brasil.

---

### Exemplos mais antigos

Encontrei *fulan, fuan* e *foan*, na versão portuguesa das “Flores de las leyes”, provavelmente do século XIII (o que confere com o dicionário Houaiss), já que o original é desse século (ver em [Jácome Ruiz](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maestro_Jacobo), o autor). As palavras aparecem numas fórmulas para o requerente se dirigir ao rei, em que *fulan*, etc. aparecem no lugar dos nomes relevantes. Exemplo (negrito meu):

> […] eu **fulan** me vos querello de **fuan** que me ouve de pagar en tal dya c. maravedis que lly emprestey e nõ mos pagou
> [“Versão portuguesa das ‘Flores de las leyes’”, *Revista da Universidade de Coimbra*, 1917, p. 358](https://www.google.com/search?ei=tHFZXf_FBqik1fAP8-690AY&q=%22eu%20fulan%20me%20uos%22&oq=%22eu%20fulan%20me%20uos%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...19271.22423..23299...0.3..1.339.2529.4j12j1j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.lU7G4kprur8&ved=0ahUKEwj_7-n54IzkAhUoUhUIHXN3D2oQ4dUDCAo&uact=5)

A forma *fulano* aparece no século XV; segundo Fernando Venâncio ([Dobletes e formas divergentes no português](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1366&bih=625&tbm=bks&ei=02RZXbSxMsv2kwWt54igAg&q=%22conhe%C3%A7o%20fulano%20feitor%20de%20tal%22&oq=%22conhe%C3%A7o%20fulano%20feitor%20de%20tal%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...33607.34046.0.34889.2.2.0.0.0.0.196.297.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.8GGnY5yeq_Qq), p. 4-5) terá sido um cultismo influenciado pelo castelhano:  formas populares que se tinham formado pela supressão de enes e eles intervocálicos, foram “corrigidas” pela reintegração dessas letras. Aconteceu com muitas outras palavras; por exemplo latim *gelus* > português antigo *geo* > *gelo* (mas ainda temos *geada*), latim *opponente* > português antigo *opoente* > *oponente*.

O ***sicrano*** mais antigo conhecido do Houaiss é de 1587; uma *sicrana*, na verdade:

> Não vedes aquilo mana
> não me afogo entã pouca agoa
> olhayme a **dona sicrana**
> [Jerónimo Ribeiro, “Auto do Físico”, em *Primeira parte dos autos e comédias portugueas*, 1587, folha 106](http://purl.pt/23692/3/#/223)

Mas merece também menção um exemplo para aí um século depois, numa tradução portuguesa da Bíblia (Rute 4:1):

> E Boaz subio á porta, e assentou se ali; e eis que o redimidor, de que Boaz tinha fallado, hia passando ; e disse lhe, **ó fulano ou cicrano**, desvia te para cà, assenta te aqui : e desviou se para ali, e se assentou.
> [A Biblia Sagrada, traduzida por João Ferreira d’Almeida (1628-91)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=h3tjAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA277&dq=cicrano&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVg-Kni-TVAhXGLhoKHT2YBoM4rAIQ6AEIwwIwLA#v=onepage&q=cicrano&f=false)

Podem ver que traduções posteriores, como [esta](https://www.bibliaonline.com.br/aa/busca?q=rute%204%3A1) e [esta outra](https://www.bibliacatolica.com.br/biblia-ave-maria/rute/4/) usaram um estilo um pouco diferente.

O ***ciclano*** mais antigo que conheço é mesmo a menção do [dicionário do Raphael Bluteau em 1720](https://books.google.pt/books?id=tMESsATvdyEC&pg=PA640&dq=siclano&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKucKZiOnVAhVD2xoKHa_0D3oQ6AEI2gIwMA#v=onepage&q=siclano&f=false).

Finalmente, o ***beltrano*** mais antigo indicado no Houaiss é de 1890, mas eu encontrei vários a partir de 1822:

> […] donde lhes veio o conhecimento de que em fulano e sicrano, melhor de em **beltrano**, se reunem essas relevantes qualidades e condições?
> [“Portugal—Continuação do Juizo sobre o Decreto das Eleições”, *O Conciliador*, Maranhão, 13 de Novembro de 1822, p. 1.](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=749524&pesq=beltrano&pasta=ano%20182)

Comment: No Brasil existe uma cidade com nome de Francisco Beltrão.

Comment: @white, estive a ver; paisagem bonita. Eu não conheço nenhum Beltrão. Acho que nunca conheci. Mas é nome antigo: há um "frey Beltrã de valuerde" ('Valverde') mencionado em 1273 em Santarém; vários no sXIV, escrito ora *Beltrã* ora *Beltram*; e encontrei a foram moderna, *Beltrão*, a partir de 1657.

Comment: Aqui no Brasil é comum dizermos "ciclano". As únicas pessoas que já ouvi falar "cic**r**ano" foram meus professores de português.

Comment: @Bruno, desconhecia. Mas já se usou em Portugal, e aparece já em 1720. Adicionei um parágrafo sobre o assunto.