# Saudação seguida de dois vocativos em e-mails formais

Tags: pontuação, email

A norma culta da língua diz que deve-se escrever a saudação seguida de vírgula e vocativo. Porém no caso em que estou enviando um e-mail direcionado a duas ou mais pessoas, qual seria a forma correta?

> bom dia, fulano e ciclano

> bom dia, fulano, ciclano

> bom dia, fulano ciclano

Comment: Fabrício G, o mais amiúde, pôr ou não uma vírgula depende de se na frase falada tem pausa ou mudança de tom. P.ex., «Eu amo, Deus», mesmo sem pausa, ela difere de «Eu amo Deus» pela mudança de tom, enquanto, «Eu amo Deus» não tem mudança **assim**. Outro é «Comprarei queijo, perfumes rosas [...]» , que é diferente de «comprarei queijo, perfumes, rosas» pela mudança na voz. Assim, «Bom dia, fulano e ciclano» e «Bom dia, fulano, ciclano» estão certos e diferem. A frase «Bom dia, fulano ciclano» não faz sentido literal, mas literário pode fazer, talvez para indicar uma fala rápida e descuidada.

Comment: E mais uma vez @Schilive dá uma boa resposta num comentário. :-)

Comment: Ah... o tal [ciclano que não existe](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4689/de-onde-surgiram-os-termos-fulano-beltrano-e-sicrano) :)

Comment: sicrano, com r.

Comment: @Lambie, só para clarificar: se seguires o link verás que *ciclano* existe; já há mais de 300 anos. Mas há quem insista que não existe ou que é erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ver isto bem é melhor termos mesmo dois nomes: por exemplo, Ana Morais e Afonso Maia. Numa coisa realmente formal será a tua primeira sugestão:

> Bom dia, Ana Morais e Afonso Maia.

A última, nem pensar. Ficaria:

> Bom dia, Ana Morais Afonso Maia

Isto seria a maneira de nos dirigirmos a uma pessoa chamada Ana Morais Afonso Maia, não a duas pessoas. Não havendo esse nome, e sim uma Ana Morais e um Afonso Maia, os recipientes compreenderiam, mas seria o oposto de formal: seria escrita atabalhoada.

A do meio é única que pode gerar dúvidas. Aquilo que é aceite em ambiente informal varia ao longo do tempo e de ambiente para ambiente; e há diferentes níveis de formalidade. No entanto, o padrão é os dois últimos itens de uma lista virem separados por um *e* e não por vírgula. Pode ser que haja ambiente formais em que se tenha normalizado o uso de usar só vírgulas, mas na dúvida, vai pelo seguro, e separa os dois últimos nomes com um *e*. Ninguém te poderá censurar. Comparemos as duas possibilidades noutra situação:

> Fui a um safári. Vi leões, gazelas, hienas e zebras.
> Fui a um safári. Vi leões, gazelas, hienas, zebras...

A primeira possibilidade pede um ponto final no fim: terminaste a enumeração. A segunda faz sentido com reticências no fim, indicando que viste mais animais que além dos indicados. Na fala, isto corresponde a uma maneira descontraída de falar; imagina aquilo dito com bastante ênfase em cada animal. Só que esta entoação não é apropriado numa comunicação formal, e definitivamente não no vocativo

Comment: A cena que "Bom dia, fulano, ciclano." me traz a mente é bastante formal, em que a pessoa faz uma pausa a cada vírgula, acompanhada de uma vênia às pessoas a quem se dirige. Nesse caso o "e" não caberia, mas também talvez reticências ou pontos fossem melhores que a vírgula.

Comment: @stafusa, sim, tu podes fazer isso numa comunicação oral. Mas vais tentar reproduzir isso numa comunicação escrita?

Comment: @stafusa, pensando bem, acho que pode funcionar, mas com títulos para dar a ideia de solenidade; e parece-me que não começaria com *bom dia*; simplesmente: "Exmª Srª Ana Morais, Exmº Sr. Afonso Maia:" Só "Bom dia, Ana Morais, Afonso Maia:" fica ambíguo: na comunicação oral tu serves-te da entoação, mas na escrita estás limitado.

Comment: Entre ciclano e entoação fica um pouquinho esquisito. :)

Comment: Sim, @Jacinto , tenho em mente mais algo como um diálogo num livro que o cabeçalho de uma carta.

Comment: @stafusa, aí tens mais possibilidades. O contexto ajuda o leitor a imaginar a cena. E podes até incluir explicações. *Dirigiu-se a eles respeitosamente. "Cara Ana; Sr. Maia; Sr. Martins, muito bom dia a todos", disse ele com uma vénia a cada um*.

Comment: Isso mesmo, @Jacinto. Seria relevante o bastante para incluir esse na resposta?

Comment: @stafusa, creio que merece uma nota. Vou ver se encontro exemplos escritos.